# How to use selenium IDE to generate HTML report

Tags: gwt, selenium, selenium-ide

My project is written by GWT, now I am using selenium IDE to record steps I made for every page. My question is how to generate the HTML report after executing the test suite in selenium IDE. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Selenium Builder ( or Selenium IDE) , you can save-as type of "Java TestNG" file.  Then, if you execute the class using TestNG, it will auto-generate a report for you.